# Why does Clipboard.HasFormat( CF_HDROP ) return false in FormCreate

Tags: delphi, clipboard

Why does Clipboard.HasFormat( CF_HDROP ) return false in FormCreate even though the clipboard contains Shell formats?

Edit

```
procedure TFormMain.FormCreate( Sender: TObject );
begin
  if Clipboard.HasFormat( CF_HDROP ) then
    MessageDlg( 'true', mtInformation, [ mbOK ], 0 )
  else
    MessageDlg( 'false', mtInformation, [ mbOK ], 0 );
end;
```

This returns false but MyIdleHandler returns true:

```
Application.OnIdle := MyIdleHandler; 

procedure TFormMain.MyIdleHandler(Sender: TObject; var Done: Boolean); 
begin 
    Paste1.Enabled := Clipboard.HasFormat( CF_HDROP ); 
end;
```

Comment: There is no need for the `= True` parts.

Comment: On my system, it works even in the `OnCreate` event handler of a form...

Comment: But that part is not failing?

Comment: No the `= True` parts are just superfluous -- they cause no harm.

Comment: Any ideas why this might fail to work on my system?  Win 7, Delphi 2010.

Comment: Perhaps there is some delay before clipboard recognises that it has the format? Move the line `Paste1.Enabled := ( Clipboard.HasFormat( CF_HDROP ) );` into Paste action's OnUpdate event to see does it make difference, ie `(Sender as TAction).Enabled := Clipboard.HasFormat( CF_HDROP );`

Comment: (After all, `SomeAction.Enabled := SomeBooleanStatement` statements *are supposed to* be run in the `OnUpdate` events of the corresponding actions.)

Comment: I tried moving it to FormActivate but no change... I usually do not use Actions...  so I added an ActionManager and added a procedure CanPasteAction1 but that fails as well?

Comment: Use actions properly. Control all UI element enabled, visible, caption etc. properties in OnUpdate handlers. Don't do it anywhere else.

Comment: Preferably the OnUpdate handler for the TActionList. See also: http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/27058

Comment: I want to make sure I understand your question. When you click the Copy button, your program copies the selected files to the clipboard, and immediately afterward, the clipboard reports that it has cf_HDrop data. But if you close and restart your program, then the clipboard no longer reports that it has that data format (as evidenced by the Paste button being disabled). Is that a correct summary?

Comment: I am nearly positive that the format is present... I have a clipboard viewer that indicates this.  If I copy the file to the clipboard with a dxbarbuttonclick (Copy1Click) the paste button becomes enabled.  I restart the app without changing the clipboard contents and the paste button is disabled... the shell format should be present because I do not change the clipboard when the app is restarted.

Comment: I copied a file using windows explorer then ran my app.  It returns true... so the problem appears to be the JamShellList1.InvokeCommandOnSelected( 'copy' );  Boy this is strange.

Comment: @Bill - You don't have to be nearly positive, just right click on the desktop and see if 'paste' is enabled..

Comment: @Rob Kennedy - ok... tested on the desktop... paste is enabled after JamShellList1.InvokeCommandOnSelected( 'copy' ); Paste button is enabled in app after copy but remains disabled after restart.

Comment: @Bill: Yes, but that does ***NOT*** prove that `HasFormat` returns `false` in `FormCreate`.

Comment: @Bill: If I were you, I'd create a *new* VCL Forms application, and do nothing more than `if Clipboard.HasFormat(CF_HDROP) then ShowMessage('got it')` in the `OnCreate` event of the main form (of course you also have to add the `Clipbrd` unit to either of the `uses` clauses). Then tell us what happens when you run the program.

Comment: @andreas extremely sound advice, but will it be heeded?

Comment: Does the Paste1 action or menu item have an OnExecute or OnClick event handler? If not, then it will never be enabled.

Comment: @Bill, please don't use the 'enabledness' of an action/menu item/button as an indicator of the return value of `HasFormat`. I see that you still do this in the `OnIdle` code. In addition, don't use `OnIdle`. Instead, you can compare the `OnCreate` event with a `OnClick` event.

Comment: In addition, there is a very, very small chance that you are right and the rest of us are wrong, that is, perhaps there *is* a problem with calling `HasFormat` in the `OnCreate` of the form. I really don't think so, but the probability for such an event is still strictly positive, and so it would be helpful if you told us the version of Delphi and the version of Windows that you use.

Comment: @Andreas Rejbrand - I am using Delphi 2010 and Windows 7.  The JamShellBrowser controls are commercial shell controls - one of the few remaining vcl shell controls that still has support.  I am driving myself nuts today so I guess I'll give up on this for awhile. I appreciate everyone's comments.  A very simple application with just a Copy and Paste ExpressBars buttons and two shell controls acts correctly, so at this point I do not understand what is going on with the other app.

Answer (score 1):

It returns true. I don't know if you can/should apply it to the Paste1 button (or whatever it is) until the form has been created, but this shows that it DOES return true, if there's a file object on the clipboard:

```
procedure TForm2.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if  Clipboard.HasFormat( CF_HDROP ) then
    MessageDlg('true', mtInformation, [mbOK], 0)
  else
    MessageDlg('false', mtInformation, [mbOK], 0);
end;
```

In my case, it shows "true" if I first copy a file to the clipboard, false otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is most likely **not** the one you think it is.

```
Clipboard.HasFormat(CF_HDROP);
```

is probably `true` even in your `FormCreate` procedure. Try this with

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if Clipboard.HasFormat(CF_HDROP) then
    ShowMessage('Yes, Rejbrand was right!');
end;
```

*The rest of my answer assumes that `Paste1` is a `TAction`, which it should be. But most likely it is a menu item, isn't it? A good advice is to start using the `TActionList` and `TAction`s.*

The problem is most likely that the action isn't redy to be used yet.

After all, `SomeAction.Enabled := <something>` statements are supposed to be run in the `OnUpdate` events of the corresponding actions. For instance,

```
procedure TForm1.ActionPasteExecute(Sender: TObject);
begin
  RichEdit1.Paste;
end;

procedure TForm1.ActionPasteUpdate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ActionPaste.Enabled := Clipboard.HasFormat(CF_TEXT);
end;
```

The `OnUpdate` event is executed *exactly* when the status of the action *needs* to be determined, e.g. when a popup menu containing a menu item with the action is shown.

Comment: I am using a developerexpressbars menu and button controls without actions.  This will fail unless I use actions?  No.. The debugger with break points shows that Clipboard.HasFormat(CF_HDROP) is false.

Comment: @Bill: In that case, you should *really* update your question and remove all irrelevant and misleading parts of it. If you *know* that `Clipboard.HasFormat(CF_HDROP)` is false in `FormCreate`, then why do you include so much about other, irrelevant, parts of your program, such as `Paste1` and `JamShellTree1`? A good question (at SO and elsewhere) is one in which a *minimal* code displaying the problem (and nothing else) is provided...

Comment: @ Andreas Rejbrand - I included the Paste and JamShellTree to demonstrate that the Clipboard.HasFormat(CF_HDROP) was working as expected in one event but not in the other...

Comment: @Bill, yes, but this adds to the problem a lot of new potential subissues, not to mention the fact that most of us have no idea what a `TJamShellTree` is! In addition, as I said previously, the fact that the button (or menu item or whatever) isn't enabled when the form appears ***DO NOT*** in any way prove that `HasFormat` returned false in `FormCreate`! A *much* better test, at both places, is `if HasFormat... then ShowMessage('true')` or even `if HasFormat... then  beep`.

Comment: Ok problem solved.  The paste button is enabled when the file format is present and disabled when not present.... not the best way... but at least it works now...Application.OnIdle := MyIdleHandler;

procedure TFormMain.MyIdleHandler(Sender: TObject; var Done: Boolean);
begin
 Paste1.Enabled := Clipboard.HasFormat( CF_HDROP );
end;

Comment: Why the negative vote?  I was just trying to demonstrate a problem.

Comment: @Bill: Because the way you tried to demonstrate it is very bad, and it is unclear, to say the least, if the assumptions you make in your question are valid or not.

Comment: @ Andreas Rejbrand- yes I understand it is ugly... but so far it is the only thing that works...  I also said in follow up that the debugger showed that Clipboard.HasFormat( CF_HDROP ) returned false ans subsequent test with show message also was false.

Comment: @Bill: Are you absolutely, 100 %, positively, sure that you don't get a message box if you create a NEW VCL application and do `if HasFormat... then ShowMessage('hello world')` in the `OnCreate` event of the main form?

Comment: @bill don't use OnIdle, just use OnUpdate of your action. You are thrashing around without knowledge or understanding. Slooow down! Change things one at a time. Build up understanding.wn! Change things one at a time. Build up understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Clipboard.HasFormat works fine. Your problem lies elsewhere.